# Force uppercase TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-input, uppercase

How can I force the TextFormField to only have uppercase letters ?
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters lets the user switch back to lowercase, so it isn't sufficient for what I want.

Comment: you can update your textController with uppercase

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add textInputFormatter to text field

```
TextField(inputFormatters: [UpperCaseTextFormatter()]),
```

formatter class

```
class UpperCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(text: newValue.text.toUpperCase(), selection: newValue.selection);
  }
}
```

Comment: But it does not show upper case letters on keyboard!

Comment: To make the keyboard also caps all the time you need to set `keyboardType: TextInputType.text` and `textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters` to the TextField.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this to your `TextFormField`

```
inputFormatters: [UpperCaseTextFormatter()],
 textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
```

**Full code**

```
TextFormField(
      autofillHints: [AutofillHints.name],
      inputFormatters: [UpperCaseTextFormatter()],
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
      labelText: "Hello World",
      hintText: '',
    ),
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the keyboard also caps all the time you need to set these properties to the TextField.

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.text
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters
```